# Returning multiple values in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops

so long story short:

```
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
user_hand = []
computer_hand = []

def draw(x):
  for c in range(0, x):
    card = random.choice(cards)
  return card

user_hand.append(draw(1))
    
print(user_hand)
```

Trying to get a function together that will loop through the cards list and pick a random item, however many times as specified by X, however no matter the number plugged into

```
user_hand.append(draw(x))
```

it always returns only 1 card, quite stumped. Any ideas? Thought it was the return in the function as return ends a code block when it's called but i wasn't sure.

Comment: Put `user_hand.append(random.choice(cards))` instead of `card = random.choice(cards)`. Then call draw(x) without to append part. However, this will draw cards with replacement, I am not sure if this is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `card` is getting overwritten in each iteration and you only return the last value.

You can create a list and return the list instead:

```
def draw(x):
  random_cards = []
  for c in range(0, x):
    card = random.choice(cards)
    random_cards.append(card)
  return random_cards

user_hand.extend(draw(1))  # further you'll need extend here else it will create a list of lists
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this way

```
def draw(x):
  result=[] 
  for c in range(0, x):
     card = random.choice(cards)
     result.append(card) 
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick cards without replacement, the [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) function does what you want.

```py
def draw(x):
  return random.sample(cards, x)

user_hand.extend(draw(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem lies in the value you are passing to `draw()`
   as `range` function iterates over the `start` and `end` point so passing one will return you only one value!
2. You also need to add another `list` to append the `random choices` selected during `range()`